# I want guidance regarding High Efficiency Video Coding

Tags: hevc

I am new to High Efficiency Video Coding. Can anyone guide me of any book or article that can help me in understanding its code in C++. Tips and guidance regarding its understanding are also invited. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend one of these two books for understanding the mechanisms of HEVC:

[Also contains general introduction to Hybrid Video Coding](http://www.springer.com/engineering/signals/book/978-3-662-44275-3)

[Also contains chapters about hardware architecture](http://www.springer.com/engineering/signals/book/978-3-319-06894-7)

If you know very little about Hybrid Video Coding so far, i'd recommend the first one.

Furthermore, you will definitely need the [HEVC Recommendation](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=11885). This is very close to the reference software. For specific parts of HEVC, you might want to search for articles that go into more detail (e.g. for CABAC, check [this article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1218195). Although it's about CABAC in AVC, it explains very well the CABAC principle and it didn't change too much for HEVC).